# Error in imputation values with missing values in MFA

Tags: r, pca, missing-data, imputation

My data structure is based in 151 individuals x 51 variables (1 categorical variable made up by 3 categories or groups(OO, NUTS, LFD), and 50 continuous numerical variables). The background of the experiment is based in 3 interventions in which patients go through different treatments. The variables are gene expression results in the form of numbers, which I intend to form clusters or to observe groups.

Of course, there are MISSING values. The missing values due to lack of samples of the individuals could be related to the clinical trial itself. However, in my database, the one I am going to attach a slice sample, missingness I would say is completely at random. Why is that? The individuals that attended to periodical meetings, get their blood collected and afterwards due to processing erros, have several genes amplified, and others not amplified, from my standpoint, is random. It is true that in the origin could be related somehow to the clinical trial.

Reviewing the potential approaches, I found the missMDA package, which I have been reviewing lately. My first doubt, which I think is correct is to confirm if the MFA is the best approach to analyse my database. Other options could be:

- PCA excluding the categorical variable to run quantitative variables?
- FAMD looks like more to combine quantitative and qualitative, not very much as a grouping variable as it is my case

The 'gene' example database (provided in missMDA package) is similar to mine, and the approach is **MFA**, and the theorical basis (I am not an expert) looks like to me correct. However following the steps in '[missMDA: A Package for Handling Missing Values
in Multivariate Data Analysis](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v070i01)' I find the next errors (I have tried several options formulating the group):

```
#The ncp estimated excluding the group using PCA approach (just quantiative continuous variabes was 5,  the variables are scaled type = "s"

res.mfa <- imputeMFA(PCA[, -1], group = c(2:51), type = "s", ncp = 5)

# Error in if (type[g] == "s") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

res.mfa <- imputeMFA(df[, -1], group = 50, type = "s", ncp = 5)

#Error in (cumsum(group.mod)[g - 1] + 1):cumsum(group.mod)[g] : NA/NaN argument
```

The df example reduced to body limitation  (is already standardized (scale funtion))

```
df <- structure(list(grup_int = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L), levels = c("OO", "NUTS", "LFD"), label = "GENERAL: Grupo de intervención", class = "factor"), 
    ppara = structure(c(2.882, -0.091, -0.519, NA, NA, NA, 0.102, 
    NA, NA, -0.292, NA, 0.73, 0.555, -0.11, -1.022, -0.027, 0.114, 
    NA, 0.593, -0.768, -0.53, NA, NA, -0.224, -0.327, -0.952, 
    -0.185, NA, NA, -0.52, -1.175, 0.286, NA, -0.398, NA, -0.144, 
    NA, NA, NA, -0.903, NA, -0.258, -0.897, -0.751, -0.662, -0.628, 
    -0.779, NA, NA, 0.743, 0.142, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.607, -0.739, 
    -0.437, NA, -1.152, -1.272, 0.608, 1.317, -0.547, 3.081, 
    0.647, -0.799, -0.682, -0.354, NA, 0.031, NA, 1.992, 3.665, 
    NA, NA, -0.027, -0.318, -0.916, NA, NA, NA, -0.31, -1.113, 
    -0.089, -0.391, NA, 0.134, -0.574, -0.291, -0.012, NA, NA, 
    -0.607, NA, -1.018, -0.702, NA, 1.624, 0.841, 0.869, NA, 
    0.373, -0.857, 0.007, 0.099, NA, -0.613, -0.005, 1.059, 1.525, 
    2.504, NA, NA, -0.737, -0.864, NA, NA, -0.901, -0.257, 0.968, 
    NA, -0.743, -0.023, NA, NA, NA, -0.219, NA, 0.226, -0.366, 
    -0.788, NA, -0.942, -0.215, NA, -0.659, -0.532, 3.052, 1.426, 
    NA, 0.366, -0.52, 0.377, NA, 1.421, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), dim = c(151L, 
    1L), "`scaled:center`" = 1.35197894736842, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.835827593173089), 
    ppard = structure(c(0.214, -0.376, -0.152, -0.121, -0.147, 
    0.681, 0.373, 0.144, 0.291, -0.554, -0.344, -0.463, 0.565, 
    -0.612, -1.073, -0.038, 0.373, -0.801, 0.052, -0.765, -0.891, 
    0.56, 0.059, -0.396, -0.447, -0.83, -0.088, -0.543, -0.126, 
    -0.678, -0.769, 0.079, NA, -0.345, NA, -0.12, -0.845, 0.182, 
    -0.234, -0.785, 0.257, -0.035, -0.426, -0.428, -0.668, -0.51, 
    -0.626, -0.264, -0.588, -0.508, -0.184, NA, 2.647, -0.403, 
    -0.99, -0.727, 0.047, -0.487, -0.286, -0.865, -0.841, 3.273, 
    0.653, -0.439, 3.509, 0.653, -0.971, -0.298, -0.343, NA, 
    0.44, 0.143, 0.847, 5.239, 0.973, 2.861, 0.36, -0.538, 4.029, 
    -0.154, -0.361, -0.047, -0.222, -1.302, -0.047, -0.005, NA, 
    0.507, -0.244, -0.38, -0.116, -0.958, NA, -0.194, NA, -0.713, 
    -0.498, 0.239, 0.405, 1.012, 0.542, 0.22, 0.846, -0.455, 
    -0.003, 0.477, -0.096, -0.301, 0.85, 0.575, 0.606, 0.713, 
    NA, -1.197, -0.766, -0.846, -0.583, -0.53, -0.246, -1.062, 
    -0.221, -0.265, -1.083, -0.449, -1.117, -0.899, 0.146, -0.561, 
    -0.471, 0.171, -0.263, -0.33, 0.028, -0.625, -0.564, 4.08, 
    -0.444, 0.092, 0.581, 0.14, -0.112, -0.349, 0.198, 0.077, 
    NA, -0.409, NA, 0.05, 0.489, NA, 0.903), dim = c(151L, 1L
    ), "`scaled:center`" = 1.40111428571429, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.811830324669782), 
    pparg = structure(c(1.298, -0.171, 0.056, 0.017, -0.428, 
    0.257, 0.719, -0.1, 1.28, -0.19, 0.344, -0.629, 1.572, -0.713, 
    -0.739, 1.027, 0.22, -0.321, -1.283, -1.283, 0.1, -0.38, 
    0.257, -0.325, -0.572, -0.705, -0.442, -1.129, NA, -1.129, 
    -0.869, 2.129, NA, 0.044, NA, -0.352, -0.568, 1.976, -0.823, 
    -0.843, 0.529, -0.046, -0.223, -0.646, -0.308, 0.227, 0.028, 
    -0.352, -0.097, 0.054, -0.512, NA, 3.624, 0.399, -0.588, 
    -0.986, -0.672, -0.612, 0.362, -1.199, -0.896, -0.675, 0.354, 
    -0.641, 3.271, 0.3, -1.196, -0.789, -0.285, NA, -0.244, -0.156, 
    1.765, 4.562, 1.241, NA, -0.407, -0.84, 2.605, 0.016, -0.619, 
    -0.317, -0.472, -1.337, -0.555, -0.932, NA, 0.312, -0.4, 
    -1.241, 0.22, -0.937, NA, -0.134, NA, -0.241, -0.176, 0.138, 
    -0.716, 0.312, 0.061, -0.682, 0.609, 0.174, -0.07, -0.554, 
    -0.224, 0.107, 0.228, 0.491, 2.581, 1.164, NA, -0.368, -0.816, 
    -0.471, -0.126, -0.144, -0.281, -0.635, 0.618, 0.649, -1.601, 
    -0.913, -1.271, -0.756, 0.529, 0.047, -0.922, 1.729, -1.05, 
    0.01, 0.8, 1.488, 0.452, 1.876, -0.13, 0.485, -0.041, 0.211, 
    -0.859, -0.621, -0.515, -0.177, NA, -0.632, NA, -0.545, 1.322, 
    NA, 1.602), dim = c(151L, 1L), "`scaled:center`" = 1.2910652173913, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.700929843387113), 
    nr1h3 = structure(c(0.407, 0.244, -0.42, -0.013, -0.829, 
    0.492, 0.881, 0.171, -0.709, 0.22, 0.026, -0.45, 0.262, 1.012, 
    -0.847, 0.484, -0.607, -0.601, -0.821, -0.194, -0.568, 0.673, 
    -0.607, -0.458, -0.494, -0.492, 0.623, -0.93, -0.058, -0.41, 
    -0.784, 0.052, -2.094, 0.07, NA, 0.272, 0.024, 0.458, 0.832, 
    -0.75, 0.074, 0.766, -0.158, 0.463, -0.184, -0.469, -0.269, 
    -0.387, -0.337, -0.271, 1.308, NA, NA, -0.497, -0.944, -1.006, 
    -1.024, -0.783, 0.276, -1.132, -0.827, -0.343, 2.697, -0.497, 
    NA, 0.897, NA, -0.294, 0.517, NA, 0.236, 0.241, 0.679, NA, 
    2.847, 2.11, 0.069, 1.473, 4.445, NA, NA, NA, -0.207, -1.697, 
    -0.069, 0.105, NA, 1.004, NA, NA, -0.428, -1.257, NA, 1.736, 
    NA, -0.691, 0.09, 0.226, 0.674, -0.55, 0.699, -0.258, 0.906, 
    -0.691, 0.768, 0.484, -0.199, -0.62, 0.128, 0.742, 2.149, 
    0.737, NA, -1.296, NA, -0.545, 0.495, -0.888, -0.926, -0.97, 
    -0.279, -0.028, -1.396, -1.321, -1.254, -0.858, -0.592, -0.691, 
    -0.885, 0.077, 0.641, -0.643, -0.286, -0.932, -0.77, 4.228, 
    -0.589, 0.254, 0.947, -0.461, -0.469, 0.023, -0.476, -0.071, 
    NA, -0.445, NA, -0.207, 0.469, NA, 2.62), dim = c(151L, 1L
    ), "`scaled:center`" = 1.30208396946565, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.609461200104939), 
    nr1h2 = structure(c(-0.49, 0.333, -0.525, -0.673, -0.442, 
    -0.029, 0.504, 0.169, -0.193, -0.641, -0.405, 0.01, 1.152, 
    0.002, -0.478, -0.514, -0.077, -0.61, -0.404, -0.544, -0.434, 
    0.448, 0.162, -0.463, -0.447, -0.81, -0.209, -0.194, 0.637, 
    -0.427, -0.366, -0.211, -1.252, -0.205, NA, -0.003, -0.277, 
    0.027, 0.172, -0.569, 0.343, 0.601, -0.468, -0.254, 0.001, 
    0.092, -0.416, -0.224, -0.518, -0.356, -0.401, NA, 1.952, 
    -0.607, -0.721, -0.481, -0.375, -0.499, -0.01, -0.822, -0.704, 
    0.01, 0.686, -0.429, 6.483, 0.214, -0.302, 0.019, -0.323, 
    NA, 0.566, 0.441, 0.273, 2.845, 0.409, 4.469, 0.115, -0.21, 
    4.747, 0.324, -0.453, -0.528, -0.057, -0.943, -0.463, -0.127, 
    NA, 0.056, -0.343, -0.05, -0.539, -0.785, NA, -0.327, NA, 
    -0.466, -0.413, -0.181, 0.43, 0.548, -0.098, 0.565, 0.487, 
    -0.571, 0.046, 0.251, 0.113, 0.382, 0.343, 0.919, 0.215, 
    0.433, NA, -0.757, -0.711, -0.656, -0.525, -0.482, -0.268, 
    -0.714, -0.101, 0.093, -0.493, -0.626, -0.845, -0.7, -0.48, 
    -0.404, -0.668, -0.028, 0.2, -0.506, -0.078, -0.84, -0.54, 
    3.735, -0.366, -0.326, 0.271, 0.199, -0.624, -0.504, 0.573, 
    -0.131, NA, -0.212, NA, 0.092, 0.175, NA, 0.61), dim = c(151L, 
    1L), "`scaled:center`" = 1.38648936170213, "`scaled:scale`" = 1.07206008371747), 
    rxra = structure(c(0.003, -0.137, -0.372, -0.339, 0.001, 
    -0.083, 0.371, -0.04, -0.286, -0.707, -0.405, 0.067, 0.205, 
    -0.515, -0.48, -0.25, -0.28, -0.408, -0.649, -0.735, -0.722, 
    0.391, -0.008, 0.584, -0.517, -0.531, -0.268, -0.405, NA, 
    0.39, -0.025, -0.02, NA, -0.119, NA, -0.586, -0.449, -0.152, 
    -0.343, -0.126, -0.528, 0.012, -0.769, 0.074, -0.213, -0.501, 
    -0.624, -0.602, -0.847, -0.655, -0.619, NA, 2.641, -0.764, 
    -0.931, -0.833, 0.084, -0.065, -0.135, -0.77, -0.665, 0.893, 
    0.544, -0.512, 7.66, 0.111, -0.297, 0.248, -0.305, NA, 0.041, 
    0.515, 0.562, 4.191, 0.701, 1.726, -0.371, -0.225, 2.191, 
    0.063, -0.714, 0.049, 0.049, -1.099, -0.875, -0.101, NA, 
    -0.152, -0.058, 0.084, -0.564, -0.49, NA, 0.138, NA, -0.592, 
    -0.782, 0.033, 0.165, 0.161, 0.576, 1.449, 2.191, -0.21, 
    -0.182, 0.547, 0.163, 0.057, 1.104, 0.842, 0.208, 0.941, 
    NA, -0.817, -0.543, -0.4, -0.344, -0.747, -0.811, -1.077, 
    -0.334, 0.312, -0.541, -0.726, -0.872, -0.365, -0.232, 0.04, 
    -0.334, -0.111, -0.304, -0.476, 0.172, -0.389, -0.233, 3.064, 
    -0.104, -0.063, -0.049, 0.686, -0.851, -0.243, -0.098, 0.067, 
    NA, -0.076, NA, 0.112, 0.429, NA, 0.241), dim = c(151L, 1L
    ), "`scaled:center`" = 1.39937410071942, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.869319134487005), 
    rxrb = structure(c(-0.489, -0.548, 0.591, 0.137, 0.814, 0.161, 
    -0.204, -0.242, -0.408, -0.65, -0.242, 0.987, 0.468, -0.6, 
    -1.373, -0.739, -0.917, -0.565, -0.633, -0.833, -0.81, 0.509, 
    0.217, 0.388, -0.067, -0.614, -0.055, -0.185, 0.416, 0.94, 
    -0.399, 0.106, -1.652, -0.902, NA, -0.224, -0.289, -0.568, 
    0.219, -0.61, -0.913, 0.299, -0.743, -0.183, -0.251, -0.699, 
    -1.232, -0.43, -0.297, -0.664, -0.273, NA, 3.264, 0.207, 
    -0.849, -0.253, -0.134, -0.762, 0.206, -0.693, -0.627, 0.747, 
    -0.139, -0.043, 4.043, 0.643, -0.319, -0.16, -0.185, NA, 
    0.083, 0.399, 0.147, 6.611, 0.054, -1.572, 0.721, -0.009, 
    -1.597, -0.062, 1.607, 0.272, -0.169, -1.139, 1.191, 0.293, 
    NA, 0.196, 0.383, -0.531, 0.02, 3.971, NA, 0.246, NA, -0.154, 
    -0.51, 0.083, 0.838, 0.19, 0.446, 0.083, 0.219, 1.676, -0.353, 
    0.421, -0.163, 0.091, 0.758, 0.625, 0.79, 0.084, NA, -0.956, 
    -0.775, -0.26, -0.446, -0.898, -0.439, -0.713, -0.93, -0.587, 
    -0.918, -0.161, -0.408, -0.216, -0.311, -0.168, 0.107, 0.15, 
    0.634, 0.853, 0.179, -0.47, -0.796, -1.533, 0.429, -0.155, 
    0.578, 0.741, 0.193, 0.067, -0.334, -0.016, NA, -0.006, NA, 
    0.053, 0.837, NA, -0.265), dim = c(151L, 1L), "`scaled:center`" = 1.39233333333333, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.828513485248186), 
    cyp27a1 = structure(c(-0.366, -0.342, -0.257, -0.731, 0.498, 
    -0.251, 1.016, -0.209, 0.086, -0.84, 0.399, -0.466, 0.022, 
    -0.54, -0.085, 0.018, -0.248, -0.82, -0.666, -0.821, -0.443, 
    0.187, -0.135, -0.433, 0.494, -0.57, -0.332, -0.088, NA, 
    -0.004, -0.705, 0.502, NA, -0.313, NA, -0.471, -0.423, -0.398, 
    -0.272, -0.82, 0.102, 0.183, -0.703, -0.155, -0.437, -0.427, 
    -0.739, -0.292, -0.586, -0.574, -0.284, NA, NA, -0.42, -1.099, 
    -0.879, -0.527, -0.609, -0.227, -0.827, -0.765, 6.111, 1.02, 
    -0.66, NA, 0.53, -0.424, 0.055, -0.184, NA, 0.633, 0.364, 
    0.418, NA, 0.229, 2.879, -0.264, -0.285, 3.73, 0.569, 0.053, 
    -0.368, -0.2, -1.217, -0.249, -0.318, NA, 0.37, 0.15, -0.23, 
    0.258, -0.623, NA, 0.183, NA, -0.321, -0.534, 0.537, -0.046, 
    0.809, 0.899, 1.415, 1.484, -0.158, -0.109, 0.863, -0.256, 
    0.281, 0.94, 1.062, 1.988, 0.064, NA, -0.455, -0.959, -0.437, 
    -0.657, -0.82, 0.022, -0.927, -0.821, 0.878, -1.189, -0.121, 
    -1.278, -0.811, -0.653, -0.54, -0.576, -0.266, 0.11, -0.433, 
    -0.075, -0.617, -0.682, 4.587, 0.149, -0.146, 0.384, 0.917, 
    -0.38, -0.17, 0.082, -0.301, NA, -0.176, NA, 0.135, -0.007, 
    NA, 2.875), dim = c(151L, 1L), "`scaled:center`" = 1.37367647058824, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.862860015103544), 
    abca1 = structure(c(-0.275, 0.339, -0.655, -0.414, -0.611, 
    0.548, -0.053, -0.25, 0.157, -0.472, -0.555, -0.329, 0.027, 
    -0.017, -0.442, 0.044, -0.191, -0.52, -0.685, -0.778, -0.503, 
    0.33, 0.045, -0.593, -0.279, -0.651, -0.192, 0.161, -0.159, 
    0.023, -0.304, 1.422, NA, -0.06, NA, -0.379, -0.488, -0.313, 
    -0.336, -0.056, -0.7, -0.563, -0.631, -0.275, -0.742, -0.394, 
    -0.655, -0.432, -0.616, -0.642, -0.141, NA, 0.3, -0.336, 
    -0.975, -0.667, -0.418, -0.325, 0.318, -0.852, -0.577, -0.766, 
    0.772, -0.559, 7.974, 0.385, -0.653, -0.261, -0.474, NA, 
    -0.007, 0.203, 0.908, 2.893, 1.629, 1.134, -0.125, 0.149, 
    4.345, 1.047, 0.223, -0.071, -0.296, -0.814, -0.64, 0.255, 
    NA, -0.277, -0.065, 0.479, -0.375, -0.422, NA, 0.292, NA, 
    -0.422, 0.515, 0.309, 0.11, 0.717, 0.468, 1.66, 1.869, -0.286, 
    0.075, 0.288, 0.092, -0.088, 0.473, -0.19, 0.548, 0.37, NA, 
    -0.824, -0.697, -0.561, -0.549, -0.529, -0.846, -0.768, -0.818, 
    0.101, -0.316, -0.727, -0.192, -0.498, -0.784, 0.324, -0.654, 
    0.626, -0.297, -0.268, -0.002, -0.21, -0.193, 2.531, 0.516, 
    -0.403, -0.064, 0.461, -0.481, 0.154, 0.215, -0.275, NA, 
    -0.527, NA, -0.642, 0.003, NA, 0.59), dim = c(151L, 1L), "`scaled:center`" = 1.66513571428571, "`scaled:scale`" = 1.46050537823946)), row.names = c("50109018", 
"50109019", "50109025", "50109026", "50109027", "50118001", "50202099", 
"50203004", "50203006", "50203008", "50203009", "50203010", "50203011", 
"50203012", "50203013", "50203014", "50203015", "50203016", "50203017", 
"50203019", "50203020", "50203022", "50203026", "50203027", "50203029", 
"50203030", "50203031", "50203032", "50430001", "50508026", "50508027", 
"50521001", "50521002", "50527001", "50601001", "50705001", "60901020", 
"60901021", "60901023", "60901024", "60901026", "60901027", "60901028", 
"60901029", "60901030", "60901031", "60901033", "60901034", "60901035", 
"60901036", "60901037", "60901038", "70107034", "70111021", "70111022", 
"70111023", "70111024", "70201047", "70204055", "70204056", "70211014", 
"70710002", "70713001", "70713002", "70802011", "70802012", "70802013", 
"70802015", "71801001", "71801002", "71801003", "110104017", 
"110104019", "110104023", "110104024", "110104027", "110104028", 
"110104029", "110104030", "110110005", "110113001", "110113003", 
"110113005", "110113006", "110113007", "110113008", "110606056", 
"110606061", "111201006", "111201007", "111201014", "111201017", 
"111201019", "111201026", "111202007", "111202009", "111202015", 
"120715011", "120715012", "120715019", "120715020", "120715021", 
"120715022", "120715025", "120715026", "120715027", "120715029", 
"120715030", "120715032", "120715033", "120715034", "120715035", 
"120715037", "130102008", "130102009", "130102010", "130102012", 
"130102013", "130102014", "130104004", "130105044", "130105045", 
"130106034", "130106037", "130106038", "130108008", "130108009", 
"140101088", "140101091", "140101096", "140101097", "140101099", 
"140102087", "140102088", "140102089", "140102090", "140102092", 
"140102095", "140103019", "140103020", "140103023", "140103024", 
"140103026", "140103027", "140103028", "140103029", "140103030", 
"140103033", "140103035", "140103036", "140103038"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there was a problem where the number of groups is 1.  There are a few lines of code that look like:

```r
for (g in 2:length(group)) 
  ind.var[[g]] <- (cumsum(group.mod)[g - 1] + 1):cumsum(group.mod)[g]
```

With one group, this fails because rather than counting up from 2 to the number of groups, it's counting down from 2 to 1.  If you make this line active only if the `length(group) > 1` with an `if()` statement, then it works.  I implemented this in a fork of the `missMDA` package from CRAN.  Here's how an example.

```r
df <- structure(list(grup_int = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
                                            1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
                                            1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                            2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            3L), levels = c("OO", "NUTS", "LFD"), label = "GENERAL: Grupo de intervención", class = "factor"), 
                     ppara = structure(c(2.882, -0.091, -0.519, NA, NA, NA, 0.102, 
                                         NA, NA, -0.292, NA, 0.73, 0.555, -0.11, -1.022, -0.027, 0.114, 
                                         NA, 0.593, -0.768, -0.53, NA, NA, -0.224, -0.327, -0.952, 
                                         -0.185, NA, NA, -0.52, -1.175, 0.286, NA, -0.398, NA, -0.144, 
                                         NA, NA, NA, -0.903, NA, -0.258, -0.897, -0.751, -0.662, -0.628, 
                                         -0.779, NA, NA, 0.743, 0.142, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.607, -0.739, 
                                         -0.437, NA, -1.152, -1.272, 0.608, 1.317, -0.547, 3.081, 
                                         0.647, -0.799, -0.682, -0.354, NA, 0.031, NA, 1.992, 3.665, 
                                         NA, NA, -0.027, -0.318, -0.916, NA, NA, NA, -0.31, -1.113, 
                                         -0.089, -0.391, NA, 0.134, -0.574, -0.291, -0.012, NA, NA, 
                                         -0.607, NA, -1.018, -0.702, NA, 1.624, 0.841, 0.869, NA, 
                                         0.373, -0.857, 0.007, 0.099, NA, -0.613, -0.005, 1.059, 1.525, 
                                         2.504, NA, NA, -0.737, -0.864, NA, NA, -0.901, -0.257, 0.968, 
                                         NA, -0.743, -0.023, NA, NA, NA, -0.219, NA, 0.226, -0.366, 
                                         -0.788, NA, -0.942, -0.215, NA, -0.659, -0.532, 3.052, 1.426, 
                                         NA, 0.366, -0.52, 0.377, NA, 1.421, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), dim = c(151L, 
                                                                                                          1L), "`scaled:center`" = 1.35197894736842, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.835827593173089), 
                     ppard = structure(c(0.214, -0.376, -0.152, -0.121, -0.147, 
                                         0.681, 0.373, 0.144, 0.291, -0.554, -0.344, -0.463, 0.565, 
                                         -0.612, -1.073, -0.038, 0.373, -0.801, 0.052, -0.765, -0.891, 
                                         0.56, 0.059, -0.396, -0.447, -0.83, -0.088, -0.543, -0.126, 
                                         -0.678, -0.769, 0.079, NA, -0.345, NA, -0.12, -0.845, 0.182, 
                                         -0.234, -0.785, 0.257, -0.035, -0.426, -0.428, -0.668, -0.51, 
                                         -0.626, -0.264, -0.588, -0.508, -0.184, NA, 2.647, -0.403, 
                                         -0.99, -0.727, 0.047, -0.487, -0.286, -0.865, -0.841, 3.273, 
                                         0.653, -0.439, 3.509, 0.653, -0.971, -0.298, -0.343, NA, 
                                         0.44, 0.143, 0.847, 5.239, 0.973, 2.861, 0.36, -0.538, 4.029, 
                                         -0.154, -0.361, -0.047, -0.222, -1.302, -0.047, -0.005, NA, 
                                         0.507, -0.244, -0.38, -0.116, -0.958, NA, -0.194, NA, -0.713, 
                                         -0.498, 0.239, 0.405, 1.012, 0.542, 0.22, 0.846, -0.455, 
                                         -0.003, 0.477, -0.096, -0.301, 0.85, 0.575, 0.606, 0.713, 
                                         NA, -1.197, -0.766, -0.846, -0.583, -0.53, -0.246, -1.062, 
                                         -0.221, -0.265, -1.083, -0.449, -1.117, -0.899, 0.146, -0.561, 
                                         -0.471, 0.171, -0.263, -0.33, 0.028, -0.625, -0.564, 4.08, 
                                         -0.444, 0.092, 0.581, 0.14, -0.112, -0.349, 0.198, 0.077, 
                                         NA, -0.409, NA, 0.05, 0.489, NA, 0.903), dim = c(151L, 1L
                                         ), "`scaled:center`" = 1.40111428571429, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.811830324669782), 
                     pparg = structure(c(1.298, -0.171, 0.056, 0.017, -0.428, 
                                         0.257, 0.719, -0.1, 1.28, -0.19, 0.344, -0.629, 1.572, -0.713, 
                                         -0.739, 1.027, 0.22, -0.321, -1.283, -1.283, 0.1, -0.38, 
                                         0.257, -0.325, -0.572, -0.705, -0.442, -1.129, NA, -1.129, 
                                         -0.869, 2.129, NA, 0.044, NA, -0.352, -0.568, 1.976, -0.823, 
                                         -0.843, 0.529, -0.046, -0.223, -0.646, -0.308, 0.227, 0.028, 
                                         -0.352, -0.097, 0.054, -0.512, NA, 3.624, 0.399, -0.588, 
                                         -0.986, -0.672, -0.612, 0.362, -1.199, -0.896, -0.675, 0.354, 
                                         -0.641, 3.271, 0.3, -1.196, -0.789, -0.285, NA, -0.244, -0.156, 
                                         1.765, 4.562, 1.241, NA, -0.407, -0.84, 2.605, 0.016, -0.619, 
                                         -0.317, -0.472, -1.337, -0.555, -0.932, NA, 0.312, -0.4, 
                                         -1.241, 0.22, -0.937, NA, -0.134, NA, -0.241, -0.176, 0.138, 
                                         -0.716, 0.312, 0.061, -0.682, 0.609, 0.174, -0.07, -0.554, 
                                         -0.224, 0.107, 0.228, 0.491, 2.581, 1.164, NA, -0.368, -0.816, 
                                         -0.471, -0.126, -0.144, -0.281, -0.635, 0.618, 0.649, -1.601, 
                                         -0.913, -1.271, -0.756, 0.529, 0.047, -0.922, 1.729, -1.05, 
                                         0.01, 0.8, 1.488, 0.452, 1.876, -0.13, 0.485, -0.041, 0.211, 
                                         -0.859, -0.621, -0.515, -0.177, NA, -0.632, NA, -0.545, 1.322, 
                                         NA, 1.602), dim = c(151L, 1L), "`scaled:center`" = 1.2910652173913, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.700929843387113), 
                     nr1h3 = structure(c(0.407, 0.244, -0.42, -0.013, -0.829, 
                                         0.492, 0.881, 0.171, -0.709, 0.22, 0.026, -0.45, 0.262, 1.012, 
                                         -0.847, 0.484, -0.607, -0.601, -0.821, -0.194, -0.568, 0.673, 
                                         -0.607, -0.458, -0.494, -0.492, 0.623, -0.93, -0.058, -0.41, 
                                         -0.784, 0.052, -2.094, 0.07, NA, 0.272, 0.024, 0.458, 0.832, 
                                         -0.75, 0.074, 0.766, -0.158, 0.463, -0.184, -0.469, -0.269, 
                                         -0.387, -0.337, -0.271, 1.308, NA, NA, -0.497, -0.944, -1.006, 
                                         -1.024, -0.783, 0.276, -1.132, -0.827, -0.343, 2.697, -0.497, 
                                         NA, 0.897, NA, -0.294, 0.517, NA, 0.236, 0.241, 0.679, NA, 
                                         2.847, 2.11, 0.069, 1.473, 4.445, NA, NA, NA, -0.207, -1.697, 
                                         -0.069, 0.105, NA, 1.004, NA, NA, -0.428, -1.257, NA, 1.736, 
                                         NA, -0.691, 0.09, 0.226, 0.674, -0.55, 0.699, -0.258, 0.906, 
                                         -0.691, 0.768, 0.484, -0.199, -0.62, 0.128, 0.742, 2.149, 
                                         0.737, NA, -1.296, NA, -0.545, 0.495, -0.888, -0.926, -0.97, 
                                         -0.279, -0.028, -1.396, -1.321, -1.254, -0.858, -0.592, -0.691, 
                                         -0.885, 0.077, 0.641, -0.643, -0.286, -0.932, -0.77, 4.228, 
                                         -0.589, 0.254, 0.947, -0.461, -0.469, 0.023, -0.476, -0.071, 
                                         NA, -0.445, NA, -0.207, 0.469, NA, 2.62), dim = c(151L, 1L
                                         ), "`scaled:center`" = 1.30208396946565, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.609461200104939), 
                     nr1h2 = structure(c(-0.49, 0.333, -0.525, -0.673, -0.442, 
                                         -0.029, 0.504, 0.169, -0.193, -0.641, -0.405, 0.01, 1.152, 
                                         0.002, -0.478, -0.514, -0.077, -0.61, -0.404, -0.544, -0.434, 
                                         0.448, 0.162, -0.463, -0.447, -0.81, -0.209, -0.194, 0.637, 
                                         -0.427, -0.366, -0.211, -1.252, -0.205, NA, -0.003, -0.277, 
                                         0.027, 0.172, -0.569, 0.343, 0.601, -0.468, -0.254, 0.001, 
                                         0.092, -0.416, -0.224, -0.518, -0.356, -0.401, NA, 1.952, 
                                         -0.607, -0.721, -0.481, -0.375, -0.499, -0.01, -0.822, -0.704, 
                                         0.01, 0.686, -0.429, 6.483, 0.214, -0.302, 0.019, -0.323, 
                                         NA, 0.566, 0.441, 0.273, 2.845, 0.409, 4.469, 0.115, -0.21, 
                                         4.747, 0.324, -0.453, -0.528, -0.057, -0.943, -0.463, -0.127, 
                                         NA, 0.056, -0.343, -0.05, -0.539, -0.785, NA, -0.327, NA, 
                                         -0.466, -0.413, -0.181, 0.43, 0.548, -0.098, 0.565, 0.487, 
                                         -0.571, 0.046, 0.251, 0.113, 0.382, 0.343, 0.919, 0.215, 
                                         0.433, NA, -0.757, -0.711, -0.656, -0.525, -0.482, -0.268, 
                                         -0.714, -0.101, 0.093, -0.493, -0.626, -0.845, -0.7, -0.48, 
                                         -0.404, -0.668, -0.028, 0.2, -0.506, -0.078, -0.84, -0.54, 
                                         3.735, -0.366, -0.326, 0.271, 0.199, -0.624, -0.504, 0.573, 
                                         -0.131, NA, -0.212, NA, 0.092, 0.175, NA, 0.61), dim = c(151L, 
                                                                                                  1L), "`scaled:center`" = 1.38648936170213, "`scaled:scale`" = 1.07206008371747), 
                     rxra = structure(c(0.003, -0.137, -0.372, -0.339, 0.001, 
                                        -0.083, 0.371, -0.04, -0.286, -0.707, -0.405, 0.067, 0.205, 
                                        -0.515, -0.48, -0.25, -0.28, -0.408, -0.649, -0.735, -0.722, 
                                        0.391, -0.008, 0.584, -0.517, -0.531, -0.268, -0.405, NA, 
                                        0.39, -0.025, -0.02, NA, -0.119, NA, -0.586, -0.449, -0.152, 
                                        -0.343, -0.126, -0.528, 0.012, -0.769, 0.074, -0.213, -0.501, 
                                        -0.624, -0.602, -0.847, -0.655, -0.619, NA, 2.641, -0.764, 
                                        -0.931, -0.833, 0.084, -0.065, -0.135, -0.77, -0.665, 0.893, 
                                        0.544, -0.512, 7.66, 0.111, -0.297, 0.248, -0.305, NA, 0.041, 
                                        0.515, 0.562, 4.191, 0.701, 1.726, -0.371, -0.225, 2.191, 
                                        0.063, -0.714, 0.049, 0.049, -1.099, -0.875, -0.101, NA, 
                                        -0.152, -0.058, 0.084, -0.564, -0.49, NA, 0.138, NA, -0.592, 
                                        -0.782, 0.033, 0.165, 0.161, 0.576, 1.449, 2.191, -0.21, 
                                        -0.182, 0.547, 0.163, 0.057, 1.104, 0.842, 0.208, 0.941, 
                                        NA, -0.817, -0.543, -0.4, -0.344, -0.747, -0.811, -1.077, 
                                        -0.334, 0.312, -0.541, -0.726, -0.872, -0.365, -0.232, 0.04, 
                                        -0.334, -0.111, -0.304, -0.476, 0.172, -0.389, -0.233, 3.064, 
                                        -0.104, -0.063, -0.049, 0.686, -0.851, -0.243, -0.098, 0.067, 
                                        NA, -0.076, NA, 0.112, 0.429, NA, 0.241), dim = c(151L, 1L
                                        ), "`scaled:center`" = 1.39937410071942, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.869319134487005), 
                     rxrb = structure(c(-0.489, -0.548, 0.591, 0.137, 0.814, 0.161, 
                                        -0.204, -0.242, -0.408, -0.65, -0.242, 0.987, 0.468, -0.6, 
                                        -1.373, -0.739, -0.917, -0.565, -0.633, -0.833, -0.81, 0.509, 
                                        0.217, 0.388, -0.067, -0.614, -0.055, -0.185, 0.416, 0.94, 
                                        -0.399, 0.106, -1.652, -0.902, NA, -0.224, -0.289, -0.568, 
                                        0.219, -0.61, -0.913, 0.299, -0.743, -0.183, -0.251, -0.699, 
                                        -1.232, -0.43, -0.297, -0.664, -0.273, NA, 3.264, 0.207, 
                                        -0.849, -0.253, -0.134, -0.762, 0.206, -0.693, -0.627, 0.747, 
                                        -0.139, -0.043, 4.043, 0.643, -0.319, -0.16, -0.185, NA, 
                                        0.083, 0.399, 0.147, 6.611, 0.054, -1.572, 0.721, -0.009, 
                                        -1.597, -0.062, 1.607, 0.272, -0.169, -1.139, 1.191, 0.293, 
                                        NA, 0.196, 0.383, -0.531, 0.02, 3.971, NA, 0.246, NA, -0.154, 
                                        -0.51, 0.083, 0.838, 0.19, 0.446, 0.083, 0.219, 1.676, -0.353, 
                                        0.421, -0.163, 0.091, 0.758, 0.625, 0.79, 0.084, NA, -0.956, 
                                        -0.775, -0.26, -0.446, -0.898, -0.439, -0.713, -0.93, -0.587, 
                                        -0.918, -0.161, -0.408, -0.216, -0.311, -0.168, 0.107, 0.15, 
                                        0.634, 0.853, 0.179, -0.47, -0.796, -1.533, 0.429, -0.155, 
                                        0.578, 0.741, 0.193, 0.067, -0.334, -0.016, NA, -0.006, NA, 
                                        0.053, 0.837, NA, -0.265), dim = c(151L, 1L), "`scaled:center`" = 1.39233333333333, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.828513485248186), 
                     cyp27a1 = structure(c(-0.366, -0.342, -0.257, -0.731, 0.498, 
                                           -0.251, 1.016, -0.209, 0.086, -0.84, 0.399, -0.466, 0.022, 
                                           -0.54, -0.085, 0.018, -0.248, -0.82, -0.666, -0.821, -0.443, 
                                           0.187, -0.135, -0.433, 0.494, -0.57, -0.332, -0.088, NA, 
                                           -0.004, -0.705, 0.502, NA, -0.313, NA, -0.471, -0.423, -0.398, 
                                           -0.272, -0.82, 0.102, 0.183, -0.703, -0.155, -0.437, -0.427, 
                                           -0.739, -0.292, -0.586, -0.574, -0.284, NA, NA, -0.42, -1.099, 
                                           -0.879, -0.527, -0.609, -0.227, -0.827, -0.765, 6.111, 1.02, 
                                           -0.66, NA, 0.53, -0.424, 0.055, -0.184, NA, 0.633, 0.364, 
                                           0.418, NA, 0.229, 2.879, -0.264, -0.285, 3.73, 0.569, 0.053, 
                                           -0.368, -0.2, -1.217, -0.249, -0.318, NA, 0.37, 0.15, -0.23, 
                                           0.258, -0.623, NA, 0.183, NA, -0.321, -0.534, 0.537, -0.046, 
                                           0.809, 0.899, 1.415, 1.484, -0.158, -0.109, 0.863, -0.256, 
                                           0.281, 0.94, 1.062, 1.988, 0.064, NA, -0.455, -0.959, -0.437, 
                                           -0.657, -0.82, 0.022, -0.927, -0.821, 0.878, -1.189, -0.121, 
                                           -1.278, -0.811, -0.653, -0.54, -0.576, -0.266, 0.11, -0.433, 
                                           -0.075, -0.617, -0.682, 4.587, 0.149, -0.146, 0.384, 0.917, 
                                           -0.38, -0.17, 0.082, -0.301, NA, -0.176, NA, 0.135, -0.007, 
                                           NA, 2.875), dim = c(151L, 1L), "`scaled:center`" = 1.37367647058824, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.862860015103544), 
                     abca1 = structure(c(-0.275, 0.339, -0.655, -0.414, -0.611, 
                                         0.548, -0.053, -0.25, 0.157, -0.472, -0.555, -0.329, 0.027, 
                                         -0.017, -0.442, 0.044, -0.191, -0.52, -0.685, -0.778, -0.503, 
                                         0.33, 0.045, -0.593, -0.279, -0.651, -0.192, 0.161, -0.159, 
                                         0.023, -0.304, 1.422, NA, -0.06, NA, -0.379, -0.488, -0.313, 
                                         -0.336, -0.056, -0.7, -0.563, -0.631, -0.275, -0.742, -0.394, 
                                         -0.655, -0.432, -0.616, -0.642, -0.141, NA, 0.3, -0.336, 
                                         -0.975, -0.667, -0.418, -0.325, 0.318, -0.852, -0.577, -0.766, 
                                         0.772, -0.559, 7.974, 0.385, -0.653, -0.261, -0.474, NA, 
                                         -0.007, 0.203, 0.908, 2.893, 1.629, 1.134, -0.125, 0.149, 
                                         4.345, 1.047, 0.223, -0.071, -0.296, -0.814, -0.64, 0.255, 
                                         NA, -0.277, -0.065, 0.479, -0.375, -0.422, NA, 0.292, NA, 
                                         -0.422, 0.515, 0.309, 0.11, 0.717, 0.468, 1.66, 1.869, -0.286, 
                                         0.075, 0.288, 0.092, -0.088, 0.473, -0.19, 0.548, 0.37, NA, 
                                         -0.824, -0.697, -0.561, -0.549, -0.529, -0.846, -0.768, -0.818, 
                                         0.101, -0.316, -0.727, -0.192, -0.498, -0.784, 0.324, -0.654, 
                                         0.626, -0.297, -0.268, -0.002, -0.21, -0.193, 2.531, 0.516, 
                                         -0.403, -0.064, 0.461, -0.481, 0.154, 0.215, -0.275, NA, 
                                         -0.527, NA, -0.642, 0.003, NA, 0.59), dim = c(151L, 1L), 
                                       "`scaled:center`" = 1.66513571428571, 
                                       "`scaled:scale`" = 1.46050537823946)), row.names = c("50109018", 
                                           "50109019", "50109025", "50109026", "50109027", "50118001", "50202099", 
                                           "50203004", "50203006", "50203008", "50203009", "50203010", "50203011", 
                                           "50203012", "50203013", "50203014", "50203015", "50203016", "50203017", 
                                           "50203019", "50203020", "50203022", "50203026", "50203027", "50203029", 
                                           "50203030", "50203031", "50203032", "50430001", "50508026", "50508027", 
                                           "50521001", "50521002", "50527001", "50601001", "50705001", "60901020", 
                                           "60901021", "60901023", "60901024", "60901026", "60901027", "60901028", 
                                           "60901029", "60901030", "60901031", "60901033", "60901034", "60901035", 
                                           "60901036", "60901037", "60901038", "70107034", "70111021", "70111022", 
                                           "70111023", "70111024", "70201047", "70204055", "70204056", "70211014", 
                                           "70710002", "70713001", "70713002", "70802011", "70802012", "70802013", 
                                           "70802015", "71801001", "71801002", "71801003", "110104017", 
                                           "110104019", "110104023", "110104024", "110104027", "110104028", 
                                           "110104029", "110104030", "110110005", "110113001", "110113003", 
                                           "110113005", "110113006", "110113007", "110113008", "110606056", 
                                           "110606061", "111201006", "111201007", "111201014", "111201017", 
                                           "111201019", "111201026", "111202007", "111202009", "111202015", 
                                           "120715011", "120715012", "120715019", "120715020", "120715021", 
                                           "120715022", "120715025", "120715026", "120715027", "120715029", 
                                           "120715030", "120715032", "120715033", "120715034", "120715035", 
                                           "120715037", "130102008", "130102009", "130102010", "130102012", 
                                           "130102013", "130102014", "130104004", "130105044", "130105045", 
                                           "130106034", "130106037", "130106038", "130108008", "130108009", 
                                           "140101088", "140101091", "140101096", "140101097", "140101099", 
                                           "140102087", "140102088", "140102089", "140102090", "140102092", 
                                           "140102095", "140103019", "140103020", "140103023", "140103024", 
                                           "140103026", "140103027", "140103028", "140103029", "140103030", 
                                           "140103033", "140103035", "140103036", "140103038"), class = "data.frame")

remotes::install_github("davidaarmstrong/missmda", force=TRUE)
library(missMDA)
res.mfa <- imputeMFA(df[, -1], group = 9, type = "s", ncp = 5)
```

Comment: It works! But somehow I need to go to your Github repository and copy the function because: Warning: package ‘missMDA’ is in use and will not be installed
I'm not quite familiarised with Github environment... and its link with R

Comment: You just need to restart you R session and install the package from GitHub before you load the package.

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge, but the modification made by you in the original package, needs to be validated by the original sustainer of missMDA?  Again thanks for te info!

Comment: @JavierHernando Yes, they should be vetted by the package maintainer.  I sent him an e-mail with my proposed changes and a link to this question.  Hopefully he will either use these changes or figure out a better way to solve the problem.  You may want to follow up with him directly.

Comment: I have seen an example published here https://groups.google.com/g/factominer-users/c/hTWoBcF4fdM?pli=1 , whic actually looks like mine (1 categorical + 1 group of quantitative variables ( with x variables)). You can see the approach recommended. It is true that is oudated, but I should make sure the correct approach, which I think it shouldn't substantially change the results.